# iOS UI control for bowling scorecard

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am working on a bowling scoring app and am having a tough time figuring out what UI classes and controls to use for the paradigm I want. Here's the ideal:

I want to draw on an ipad (in landscape) a bowling scoresheet exactly like the oldstyle paper you see in a bowling alley with the 11 boxes for each scorer. I want to be able to input scores by touch the boxes etc, be able to print an old school bowling scoresheet (with the lines etc) at the end, and have the app essentially be what I call "hot paper". I want a full scoring sheet for 5 bowlers for example inside appropriate scroll controls so an olde phart using it can pinch or swipe to move around the paper to input scores.

This is targeted at olde pharts exclusively and they want it to act like paper. While I have written simple apps with TableViews and the like, I am not sure whether to use a Collection, Grid, or what, and what is the right way to draw so that I can send the completed "paper" scoresheet to a  printer.

I am looking for some iOS genius who can recommend simply what classes I should be using for the elements - for example each row of the score sheet etc. Also shwhat elements should I use storyboards for and what should I do programmatically? I am quite storyboard challenged and usually do everything programmatically - I amgreat with making things work but awful on making them pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

[image]

Personally, I would draw/construct it entirely in code, as it so straightforwardly geometrical and repetitive. Just think of it as a hierarchy of views, each of which is itself a class that knows how to draw/construct itself. For example, MyFrameView is the box for one frame, which might or might not be the tenth frame. Then MyPlayerRowView simply gives itself ten MyFrameViews horizontally, and MySheetView gives itself five MyPlayerRowViews vertically. And presto, just three self-drawing classes so far and yet we've constructed almost the entire grid.

The only question is the underlying interactive interface. How should information be entered? What is the user to be allowed to *do*? That is a problem for *you* to solve. For example, should a MyFrameView just contain a UITextField? Or do you want the user to tap it and have some sort of "enter score" interface pop up? Those are the sorts of things you'll have to think about; in the latter case, you'll use a gesture recognizer to detect the tap and respond accordingly.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to code up, and yes I do plan on a gesture recognizer for score entry on touch etc - that to me is the ez part. My confusion is whether or which iOS classes I should derive my views from as far as organizing them - tableview, collection, etc? Or should I just code each feature those classes provide individually for my custom objects? All my apps have used classes from the UIKit and been simple enough that I could derive all my classes or customizations off simple things that already exist. I guess I need to build this from the ground up?

Comment: In your example would MyRowView be a UICollection? Would MySheetView be a UITableView?

Comment: No, they are all UIViews. That's the point. We don't need all that extra complexity.

Comment: Thank you - BTW I already have a copy of one of your books, it was very helpful!

Comment: I should add, I expect the _whole_ sheet to be larger than the iPad screen. But then just stick it into a scroll view and you're done. :)

Comment: Exactly where I am going with it! Gonna be fun going to ground zero on simple UIViews... The final goal has to be something an old timer that has no idea how to use a tablet can navigate - thus the "paper" interface.